# How to find the total number of minutes a person spent in his/her office on a particular date

Tags: python, datetime

How to find the total number of minutes a person spent in his/her office on a particular date. This is the function to calculate the different minutes but doesnt work.

**This is an example of the txt file.**

> apple,24/3/2019,10:00 AM,10:30 AM,11:30 AM,12:30 PM
>   pear,24/03/2019,9:23 AM,7:00 PM
>   orange,24/3/2019,11:57 PM
>   orange,25/3/2019,7:00 AM(O),5:00 PM,6:00 PM

```
def count_total(timing, date):
    count = 0
    start = ''

    if len(timing) == 1:
        t = timing.split()
        if t[1] == 'PM':
            hh = int(t[0]) + 12
            start = date + ' ' + str(hh) + ':00' 
            format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'
            startDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, format)

            end = date + ' 24:00:00'
            endDateTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, format)

            return (endDateTime - startDateTime)
```

Apple spent a total of 90 minutes in office on the 24 Mar 2019.
1. steps into office at 10:00AM (inclusive) and steps out of office at 10:30AM (exclusive). His time spent in
office for this session is 30 mins.
2. steps back into office at 11:30AM (inclusive) and steps out of office at 12:30PM (exclusive). His time spent in
office for this session is 60 mins.

Comment: Why do you use `12 / 24:00:00'` instead of  `10:00AM / 10:30AM `?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code

```
timeList = [
    ["apple","24/03/2019","10:00 AM","10:30 AM","11:30 AM","12:30 PM"],
    ["pear","24/03/2019","09:23 AM","07:00 PM"],
    ["orange","24/03/2019","11:57 PM"],
    ["orange","25/03/2019","07:00 AM(O)","05:00 PM","06:00 PM"]
    ]

total = []

def count_total(list):
    for i in range(len(timeList)):
        if len(timeList[i])<2:
            return False
        name = timeList[i][0]
        date = timeList[i][1]
        timeSpent = 0
        startTime = ""

        for j in range(2,len(timeList[i])):
            time = timeList[i][j].split(" ")[0]
            zone = timeList[i][j].split(" ")[1]
            if zone == "PM":
                time = time.split(':')
                if time[0]!= "12":
                    temp = int(time[0])+12
                    time = str(temp)+":"+time[1]
                else:
                    time = time[0]+":"+time[1]
            if zone.__contains__("(O)"):
                hour = int(time.split(":")[0])
                minute = int(time.split(":")[1])
                if zone.__contains__("AM"):
                    timeSpent = timeSpent + (60*hour) + minute
                elif zone.__contains__("PM"):
                    timeSpent = timeSpent + (60*hour) + minute + (12*60)

            else:
                if startTime == "":
                    startTime = time
                else:
                    time = time.split(":")
                    startTime = startTime.split(":")
                    timeMin = int(time[0])*60+int(time[1])
                    startTimeMin= int(startTime[0])*60 + int(startTime[1])
                    temp = timeMin - startTimeMin
                    timeSpent = timeSpent+temp
                    startTime = ""
        if startTime != "":
            startTime = startTime.split(':')
            startTimeMin = int(startTime[0])*60 + int(startTime[1])
            dif = 24*60 - startTimeMin
            timeSpent = timeSpent + dif
        data = [name,date,timeSpent]
        total.append(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count_total(timeList)
```

It's working by the way.